# How to backup all iOS text messages to mac or DropBox

Tags: ios, macos

How can I backup my entire text message archive to my Mac in a format that I can read? I am eventually trying to save it to DropBox, but just figuring out how to get them onto my Mac will answer everything.

Comment: You mean backup to be able to restore or file transfer in readable format?

Comment: Yes, that is correct - I will edit my quesiton

Comment: [This article](http://www.imore.com/how-view-and-move-your-imessage-history-and-attachments) covers something similar to what you want.  See if it helps you archive your messages, then you can back them up to wherever you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like [Phone View](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) or [iExplorer](https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/features/export-iphone-messages-voicemail-contacts/) to export messages from your iPhone to your computer.

Phone View:

> Save your SMS, iMessages and WhatsApp messages
>
> Search and view your texts, plus picture and video messages, even when your iPhone isn’t connected to your Mac.
>
> Export messages as beautiful PDF files.

iExplorer:

> Some text messages are meant to be saved. With iExplorer, you can keep any or all of your text messages easily, allowing you to remember special moments, preserve important data, and get more done across your devices with simple iPhone SMS backup. The beautiful, intuitive app interface lets you search and save iPhone text messages with ease.
>
> Export to PDF, CSV, TXT, all Images, all Attachments